# Accessing a dictionary from another class other than the one it was created and appended in returns blank results

Tags: swift, dictionary

I have a class that takes information from a textfield and appends it to a dictionary. After that is done I call a function from another class that adds those dictionary items to labels connected to a TableViewCell. The problem is from within that function the dictionary is blank but if I print the contents in the original class, it shows the contents just fine.

```
var vehicles = [String:String]()

@IBAction func confirmAddVehicle(_ sender: Any) {

    vehicleName = String(vehicleNameTxt.text!)

    vehicleNotes = String(vehicleNotesTxt.text!)

    vehicles[(vehicleName)] = vehicleNotes

    print(vehicles) //Here is where it will correctly show the contents

    AddVehicleToCell().AddVehicleToCellFunc() //Here is the outside function that I call
}

func AddVehicleToCellFunc() {

    print(AddVehicle().vehicles) //Here the output that I get is: [:], instead of the input

}
```

If my input for the textfield, vehicleNameTxt is "Car" and the input for the vehicleNotesTxt is "My car" what I get when I print the results out from within that class is: ["Car": "My car"] which is correct. When called from the other class, however, the result is: [:]

Comment: you are initialising a new class, you have to pass the value to your other class

Comment: http://www.programmingios.net/dont-make-a-new-instance-by-mistake/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I understand your problem and I also had these kind of problems when I started learning swift programming so then answer to your question is here:

```
      var vehicles = [String:String]()

 @IBAction func confirmAddVehicle(_ sender: Any) {

vehicleName = String(vehicleNameTxt.text!)

vehicleNotes = String(vehicleNotesTxt.text!)

vehicles[(vehicleName)] = vehicleNotes

print(vehicles) //Here is where it will correctly show the contents

AddVehicleToCell().AddVehicleToCellFunc(vehicle: vehicles) //Here is the outside function that I call
  }

 func AddVehicleToCellFunc(vehicle:[String:String]) {
  // here in the below statement you are initializing the add vehicle class. that means your vehicle is empty so you need to pass it in the function
// print(AddVehicle().vehicles) //Here the output that I get is: [:], instead of the input
print(vehicle) //this will give you what you want.

 }
```